Are social media an example of Harry Frankfurt's "bullshit"?
Harry Frankfurt in On Bullshit, states that bullshitters care not for truth. It seems that so-called social media, or antisocial media, care not for truth. It directs attention to lies and matters out of context simply to make money. If philosophy seeks truth, they are profoundly anti-philosophical. So are philosophers obliged to criticise social media as bullshit? Are democratic governments obliged to regulate them? Are there any works concerned with these questions?
This question is about social media - not consumers.
It is not about amplification. It is about publishing. Social media are publishers. The law is trying to catch up with this reality. Freedom of expression is already abridged by laws against defamation and incitement to hatred and violence.
The term bullshit is a philosophical coinage of Harry Frankfurt. By asking the question, I do not refer to particular content.
More importantly, I refer to the mode of operation - driven by algorithms devised to generate revenue.
The SEP entry on social networking is generally useful, but I am looking for philosophy which engages with the morality of the technology which drives engagement and revenue. This article explains the problem from a technical and social point of view:- Munn, L. Angry by design: toxic communication and technical architectures. Humanit Soc Sci Commun 7, 53 (2020).
Philosophy seeks truth, so a powerful source of lies and distortion should be of great concern to philosophers.
Moreover, this relates to the general question about the rule of law and to what extent the rights of minorities should be protected in a democracy.

social media are not dedicate to "search the truth". "Are philosophers obliged to criticise social media"? Maybe... philosopers interested into "social critic" must do it. "Are democratic governments obliged to regulate them?" Yes.

Although the word "bullshit" is crude, Harry Frankfurt was an academic philosopher at Princeton.

Some social media posts are true and some are false. It is a false premise to your question that social media in general is bullshit.

Philosophers criticize bullshitting generally, and that is going on in political and commercial speech, academic publications, traditional media, common gossip and pretty much everywhere else. It is not the conduit that should be criticized but the content. And there is plenty of criticism of modern culture that encourages distortions and bullshitting in particular, Critical Theory is even named after it. More specifically, see e.g. Wakeham, Bullshit as a Problem of Social Epistemology.

Regulation must not break freedom of expression in democracy, making most attempts useless.

I submitted an edit request changing the title, since I think some people are reading it and reflexively hitting downvote. That said, this question asks several subquestions; "So are philosophers obliged to criticise social media as bullshit? Are democratic governments obliged to regulate them?"--those don't seem tied to the primary question of "what is bullshit and is social media an example"

@Kaia. Thank you for this. My question seems to have been misunderstood on more than one level. I certainly did not intend to be crude. It seems to me that the moral and political consequences of social media require philosophical analysis.

@David Gudeman I refer to the mode of operation, not particular content.

@tkruse Freedom of is not absolute. There are significant abridgements. See edit.

Social media are not dedicated to the search of truth: they are not a "tool" for philosophy (see L.Strickland: "Philosophy, as it is understood and practiced in the West, is and has been generally considered to be the search for truth.")
See H.Frankfurt, On Truth (2006), Introduction:

My claim [in the previous essay on bullshit] was that bullshitters, although they represent themselves as being engaged simply in conveying information, are not engaged in that enterprise at all. Instead, and most essentially, they are fakers and phonies who are attempting by what they say to manipulate the opinions and the attitudes of those to whom they speak. What they care about primarily, therefore, is whether what they say is effective in accomplishing this manipulation. Correspondingly, they are more or less indifferent to whether what they say is true or whether it is false [emphasis added].

This means that, applying F's analysis, social media are not bullshit per se, but the widespread use of them to produce and distribute fakes is bullshit.
Useful: Keith R. Harris, Real Fakes: The Epistemology of Online Misinformation (Philosophy & Technology, 2022): "The purpose of this paper is to consider the effects of online fakes on knowledge and, in particular, the pathways by which fakes interfere with knowledge acquisition and the conditions under which they do so."

I have accepted this answer and am generally satisfied with it. However, it seems to me that in designing algorithms to drive traffic and revenue, the owners of social media are driving misinformation. In my view, this provides the legal justification for regulation of social media. Finally, the lack of concern for truth qualifies social media as bullshit.

@Meanach - agreed... the issue is that "owners" of social media (at least at the start) didn't think abouit truth but about "socializing". Then things evolved, and "get out of hand": this is why we need regulations.
